# MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Tfs2013.TeamBuild and Visual Studio Online Builds

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to run an msbuild script utilizing the ExtensionPack for 2013 TeamBuild

I can't connect to the server so I'm wondering if this is only for Server based TFS builds?

The error for the folowing BuildScript is:

```
TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException TF31002Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server
```

This is the build script

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">


  <Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MsBuild.ExtensionPack.Tasks" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TeamFoundationServerUrl>https://#####.visualstudio.com/</TeamFoundationServerUrl>
    <TeamProject>IT Development</TeamProject>
    <BuildUri></BuildUri>
    <BuildDefinitionName>Order Deploy Test</BuildDefinitionName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Default">
    <!-- Queue a new build -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Tfs2013.TeamBuild 
        TaskAction="Queue" 
        TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" 
        TeamProject="$(TeamProject)" 
        BuildDefinitionName="$(BuildDefinitionName)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm now going down the route of using TFSBuild.exe from the command line but I'm still having the same issues of being unable to connect to the TFS server. Error TFS31002

Comment: Solved ... I was using the path https://#####.visualtstudio.com/ whereas I had to use https://#####.visualtstudio.com/DefaultCollection